# Even roots and exponents power rule

Tags: roots, exponentiation

I've a question about exponents power rule applied to even roots.

**Assuming as facts**

1. $x \in \mathbb{R}$
2. $\sqrt[2n]{x^{2n}} = |x|$
3. $\sqrt[a]{x^b} = x^{b/a}$
4. the exponents power rule $({x^a})^b = x^{a b}$ is true
5. $x^{a b} = x^{b a}$

**Problem 1**

We have that $\sqrt[2n]{x^{2n}} = {x^{2n}}^{\frac{1}{2n}} = x^1 = x$ applying 3.

How is it possible that $\sqrt[2n]{x^{2n}} = x$ if 2 is true? That means that $|x| = x$ which is clearly not true.

**Problem 2**

$x^{a/b} = x^{a\frac{1}{b}} = x^{\frac{1}{b}a}$ applying 4 and 5.

But this is not true for all a and b. For instance, if $a=2, b=4$:

1. $x^{2/4} = x^{2\frac{1}{4}} = \sqrt[4]{x^2}$
2. $x^{2/4} = x^{2\frac{1}{4}} = x^{\frac{1}{4}2} = ({\sqrt[4]x})^2$

That results in saying that $ \sqrt[4]{x^2} = ({\sqrt[4]x})^2$ which is false.

Comment: The second problem results in a correct conclusion.

Comment: @Tavish how could be correct?
The first one have a domain in all R, the second one in x>=0

Comment: Any real number has two square roots $x^2=(-x)^2$. So when we use the root symbol, is is convention to take the positive real root, hence (2). Taking roots involves choices, so the exponents power rules are only true for all $a,b,x$ if $x$ is non-negative. Whenever we take a non-integer power, there are normally multiple "answers" and we always take the non-negative one if we can

Comment: This also explains Tavish's comment. The fourth root function is defined only from the non-negative reals to the non-negative reals. Both sides are, by definition, non-negative

Answer (score 1):

When you divide the exponent in $x^{2n/2n}$ you have to remember that, by definition, the square root of any number is always positive, which means that you have to get the module of the expression *before* doing the actual division

As for the second one, when you go from $\sqrt[4]{x^2}$ to $(\sqrt[4]{x})^2$ you are restricting the domain (from R to R+), which means the two are not equivalent. In order to actually make them equivalent, you have to take the absolute value of x before moving the exponents around

Comment: I don't have enougth reputation to give you a vote, but thank you very much